# Adding hibernate dependency in Eclipse with Maven and m2e plugin

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, dependencies, m2e

I've created a Java project in eclipse and added hibernate 3.5.4 dependency to pom.xml file, but the only jar that appeared in Maven Dependencies tab is slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar. How should I configure Maven or m2e plugin to add all required dependencies for Hibernate?

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>pl.edu.agh.bd2.tutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateTutorial</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.3</source>
          <target>1.2</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: can you show us the pom.xml of what you did please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When specifying a dependency with `<type>` `pom` it won't be included into your dependencies library as you are expecting (a jar file).
Here is a list of basic hibernate artifact ids that I use to include:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Replace the `${hibernate.version}` with desired version or define a property with this identifier.